# Is there a way to make a Winforms Progress bar that's set to Marquee style to be faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I set the `MarqueeAnimationSpeed` to 1, which seems to be the lowest value allowed but it's still not moving fast enough.

Are there other parameters I can tweak to make it move faster? Maybe some unmanaged win32 calls?

Comment: You can create your own `UserControl` for this that will do anything you want it to do. That's a lot more sane than trying to tweak a .NET control via win32 calls.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: 'this is a lot more sane' !?  Surely you jest.

Comment: @Boo: writing a `UserControl` like this is a trivial task. Overriding a .NET control's default behavior with win32 calls is not. Ergo my "sanity" comment.

Comment: "not fast enough" wouldn't be what an ergonomics expert would say.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Would "product manager" be equivalent?

Comment: A good product manager would also have some pity on the poor users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 1 millisecond is as low as PBM_SETMARQUEE allows.  Values below 15 make no difference, timers can't tick any faster.  Make it look like it moves faster by making the bar shorter.

Comment: I can't believe I'm now suggesting this, but might not a win32 call to `timeSetPeriod(1)` allow the progress bar to actually animate at that speed?

Comment: Ok thanks. I can make it small but it has to fill an area. Would it be possible to use multiple progressbars side by side and make it look like they are one? Because it has to have a certain width.